# Hammer.js how to enable vertical scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, hammer.js

I have a hammer.js swiper element that only allows pan left/right. I have a child element that I used a high `z-index` for it so that it go over the hammer.js element. I am able to scroll on my laptop, but on mobile I can't. How can I fix this?